# Strawberry perl, Can't locate App/Cpan.pm

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

I installed the 32 bit version of Strawberry perl(5.14.2.1). I am able to run the perl command. When ever I run the `cpan` command I get the following error:

```
Can't locate App/Cpan.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys /usr/
lib/perl5/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8
.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at /c/strawberry/perl/bin/cpan line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /c/strawberry/perl/bin/cpan line 5.
```

I migrated from the 64 bit version to the 32 bit version. The `cpan` command used to work when I was using the 64 bit version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys"? You aren't running Strawberry Perl! The `cpan` file you are running was installed by another Perl. Try

```
C:\>c:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

Comment: I had `msysgit` installed on my machine which ships with `perl.exe`. I had to fix the path to address the issue.

Comment: just put the path/to/perl before /path/to/msysgit in the PATH, like this: C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;

Comment: Hi, I don't succeed here. I have exactly the same order in my PATH but when I run `perl -` I get: `This is perl, v5.8.8 built for msys`. I want to run my strawberry perl. Thanks for help.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, Not the place to ask new questions. Either change the path so Strawberry Perl's dir comes first, or use the full path (e.g. `c:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl`) to start `perl`.