# Installing modules with Strawberry Perl 5.16.2.2 (64bit)

Tags: windows, perl, module, strawberry-perl, installation

I used to use activestate perl, but moved to strawberry perl just now because I want to install those less common used packages. However I'm having problems installing modules with Strawberry Perl 5.16.2.2 (64bit) on my Windows 7.

Having installed Strawberry Perl, I verified that perl is working fine (ref 1). However installing modules is a different story. According to the README,

"2. install additional perl modules (libraries) from http://www.cpan.org/ by

```
 c:\> cpan Module::Name"
```

But this is what I got:

```
 C:\>cpan
 Can't locate App/Cpan.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys /usr/
 lib/perl5/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8
 .8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at /d/sberry/perl/bin/cpan line 6.
 BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /d/sberry/perl/bin/cpan line 6.
```

Then I tried to config CPAN myself, via "perl -MCPAN -e shell", But this is what I got:

```
 Where is your gzip program? [/bin/gzip]
 Where is your tar program? [/bin/tar]
 Where is your unzip program? [/bin/unzip]
 Warning: make not found in PATH
 Where is your make program? []
```

But I tested, and I do can run "make" from DOS command line.

So, anyone can help me out here?

Thanks

ref 1:

C:>perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 8 subversion 8) configuration:
  Platform:
    osname=msys, osvers=1.0.11(0.4632), archname=msys
    uname='msys_nt-5.1 chomsky 1.0.11(0.4632) 2007-07-29 17:16 i686 unknown '
    config_args='-de'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    usethreads=undef use5005threads=undef useithreads=undef usemultiplicity=unde
f
    useperlio=define d_sfio=undef uselargefiles=define usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=undef use64bitall=undef uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=y, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='gcc', ccflags ='-DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -fnative-struct -fno-strict-alias
ing -pipe',
    optimize='-O3 -s -mcpu=pentium',
    cppflags='-DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -fnative-struct -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe'

```
ccversion='', gccversion='2.95.3-1', gccosandvers=''
intsize=4, longsize=4, ptrsize=4, doublesize=8, byteorder=1234
d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=12
ivtype='long', ivsize=4, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize
```

=4
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='ld2', ldflags =' -s'
    libpth=/usr/lib /lib
    libs=
    perllibs=
    libc=/usr/lib/libmsys-1.0.dll.a, so=dll, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl.a
    gnulibc_version=''
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=dll, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags=' -s'
    cccdlflags=' ', lddlflags=' -s'

Characteristics of this binary (from libperl):
  Compile-time options: MYMALLOC PERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV USE_LARGE_FILES
                        USE_PERLIO
  Built under msys
  Compiled at Jan 16 2008 13:18:22
  @INC:
    /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys
    /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/msys
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
    .

Comment: hmm, from [Strawberry perl, Can't locate App/Cpan.pm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836862/strawberry-perl-cant-locate-app-cpan-pm?rq=1) seems that my perl is not Strawberry Perl.

Comment: Ok, so the problem now boils down to, does Strawberry Perl correctly setup my environments (PATH, etc) as activestate perl does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, Strawberry Perl does correctly setup my environments (PATH, etc). I did a remove and re-install to confirm it.

Just that Strawberry Perl put its path to the end of PATH setting, which caused problem for me because my Git Extension+ has Perl as well and comes before Strawberry Perl in PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `cpnap`? (CPANPLUS)?

In my opinion, it's more user-friendly, and offers more functionality, than `cpan`